# How to use supervisord on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, supervisord

Can supervisor (http://supervisord.org) run and manage/monitor several long running python scripts (long-polling SOAP listeners) on Heroku or do i have to use a dyno for each script.
If dyno’s for each script can be used, will they restart automatically after failure or restart? (That’s basically what i need, redundancy for those scripts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is technically possible to have a Heroku dyno run some kind of parent supervisor process, that spawns and automatically restarts child processes. I have done this myself with [forever-monitor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever-monitor). My Procfile had a line for a worker [process type](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#process-types-as-templates) that ran a parent process that spawned and managed child processes.

So yes, this can be done, technically.

However, you need to carefully consider whether this is good for your use-case. An advantage of this approach is that it may enable you to reduce dyno costs (since you will be running child processes on a single dyno instead of on separate dynos). 
But this is really "working around" Heroku best practices (and the [12 Factor App](https://12factor.net/) methodology behind it).

If at all possible, it is probably better if you can allow Heroku to schedule your long running python scripts as separate worker process types, each on its own dyno(s). If you can afford to do that (cost-wise), then Heroku will automatically restart each of your scripts after failure or restart (see [Restarting](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting)). If that is all you need, then you don't need to run your own "Supervisor" at all - let Heroku take care of that for you (it does it very well).

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'll use a dyno for each process. Is there also some kind of notification system that will trigger when something is "wrong" with the process running in its dyno?

Comment: There are many ways to do that. One way is to add Papertrail as your logging service, and then to configure automatic notifications (via email, slack etc.) for Heroku errors.